# MVC Frameworks for WPF

Tags: wpf, model-view-controller

Are there any MVC frameworks available for WPF other than [Caliburn](http://www.codeplex.com/caliburn/) (which looks awesome btw)?

Comment: Technically, Caliburn is a MVVM framework with a dash of MVP thrown in. But I confuse the different flavors of MVx all the time, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Caliburn and PRISM are very nice. However if you go down the path of MVC you will miss out on the powerful 2 way binding.  Consider MVVM, it's a very clean and practical approach for WPF.  This is the pattern Microsoft used for their expression blend.

Comment: Yes MVVM is nice :) Caliburn should work well with it, I just fear that it could suffer from being forced to add too many Attributes manually, I really hate that.

Answer (score 6):

There is also [Magellan](http://www.paulstovell.com/magellan), a port of ASP.NET MVC for WPF.

Comment: I wish there was support for .NET 3.5 and vs2008. Any plans to support this? Great project btw!! :)

Comment: Magellan is great, I mixed it with ReactiveUI, then I have the best of both worlds, MVVM for view state and MVC (the controller part) for view navigation. And it works with WPF and Winforms.

Answer (score 3):

There is Composite WPF aka PRISM from Microsoft Pattern & Practices.

http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF

Answer (score 0):

one additional possibility is pureMVC (www.puremvc.org)

- it seems well-proven, has [good short doc/UML](http://puremvc.org/component/option,com_wrapper/Itemid,35/), and the project is responsive, and has been ported to .NET - there exists an WPF demo, it will be published soon but you also can contact the project owner about it.

Regards,
Paul

Comment: I've got some experience with this one from an AS3/Flash/Flex perspective. I loved it for a while, but after experiencing some of it's downsides, I've moved on to other options. Development is fast, but it leaves a mess in its wake. If you've ever had to debug after a project has been created, it's usually neither fun nor easy. Other MVC frameworks enforce better structural standards.

Answer (score 0):

A new MVC framework that works with practically and .net technology (WebForms, WinForms, WPF, Xamarin Forms) is SimpleMVC by Gateway Programming School.  This [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1197973/Demystifying-and-Simplifying-MVC-Frameworks) gives an overview and example usage.

A short example is to create a controller from SimpleControllerBase that has your business logic.  This will depend on the SimpleModelBase implementations you provide.  Implementations of ISimpleView are handled through WPF pages and controls.  The derived controller only works with the interfaces that extend ISimpleView so that the WPF parts are abstracted away.  You then use properties on the view to do two-way data-binding, just like MVVM, but with a proper layered architecture.